# Create a default index template for all indices in elasticsearch 5.2

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a way to set index related properties for all created indices by default.

previously with elasticsearch 2 I had lines like these:

```
index.number_of_replicas: 0
index.merge.scheduler.size_thread_count: 1
index.number_of_shards: 1
```

in the node configuration YAML. Now no index related configuration is allowed in node config, so how do I apply all these settings on elasticsearch startup?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like I found a solution, here's how you add a global setting to all indices:

preparations:

```
Node node = new Node(nodeSettings.build()).start();
Client client = node.client();
```

and then:

```
new PutIndexTemplateRequest("my-template-name")
                    .template("*")
                    .create(true)
                    .settings(indicesSettings.build());
client.admin().indices().putTemplate(request).actionGet();
```